# How can I calculate the time complexity of the following pseudocode:

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode

How can I calculate the time-complexity of this recursive algorithm and then use it to calculate the master theorem?

I know for the master theorem we would have a function of the following format:
T(n)=aT(b/n)+f(n)

But then to calculate the running time I can only think in generic terms like we have mainly constants, then N/2 because it splits the values on each iteration.

So I think it would be O(log(N)), maybe? But what is the T(n)=aT(b/n)+f(n) for it? How do I get this number?

```py
def Sum(A,left,right) 
      if left > right: 
          return 0 
      elif left == right: 
          return A[left] 

      mid = floor((left + right)/2) 
      lsum = Sum(A,left,mid) 
      rsum = Sum(A,mid+1,right) 
      
      return lsum + rsum
```

Comment: If `Sum` is the same function as `sum` complexity is `o(n)` where `n = len(A)`.

Comment: It isn't the same function.

Comment: Pretty obviously the complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty obviously the complexity is `O(n)`. Each element of the array is accessed exactly once.

In the formula `a = b = 2` and `f(n) = O(1)`. Solving for these values you get `O(n)`.